# Qt ActiveX retrieving the number of pages in a word document

Tags: c++, vba, qt, ms-word

I am not proficient at VBA but need to use the documentation from microsoft [the documentation form msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839342.aspx)  to retrieve the number of pages in a word document.I have tried things like in the snippet below:

```
 mWordDoc=new CustomQAxWidget("d:\\gakwandi.docx",0);

 QAxObject* selection = mWordDoc->querySubObject( "Selection" );

 QAxObject* pageNumbers = selection ->querySubObject( "PageNumbers" );

 int numberOfPages = pageNumbers->property("Count").toInt();
```

But I am getting errors like   QAxBase::dynamicCallHelper: PageNumbers: No such property in d:\gakwandi.docx [unknown] Candidates are:.....which suggests that I am somehow getting the syntax wrong somewhere.I was hopping someone more experienced with windows programming would hepl point out what I might be doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I as able to put a piece of code together to get what I wanted.Just leaving it here in case somebody else needs to do the same.Thanks again KazJaw.Your input was really helpful.

```
QAxObject*  word = new QAxObject("Word.Application", this);

//2.OPEN THE DOCUMENT
QAxObject*    doc = word->querySubObject("Documents");
doc->dynamicCall("Open(QVariant)", "d:\\gakwaya11.docx");
doc->setProperty("Visible",false);
//3.GET TO THE CONTENTS
QAxObject * activeDocument=word->querySubObject("ActiveDocument");

QAxObject * content=activeDocument->querySubObject("Content");

int mNumberOfPages = content->dynamicCall("Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)").toInt();

//doc->dynamicCall("SaveAs (const QString&)", QString("d:\\karamage.docx"));
doc->dynamicCall("Close (boolean)", false);
word->dynamicCall("Quit (void)");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Word VBA you could check number of pages in this way:

```
? ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
```

or

```
? ActiveDocument.Content.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
```

I don't know the way to put it in C++ syntax but hope you could figure it out o your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,but ActiveDocument retreives an already opened word document.Is it possible to retreive the page count on a docx that is not opened?Just like I did on  d:\\gakwandi.docx  in the snippet above. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Thanks again,Is there a good document on WORD VBA that you could recommend to understand the word object model,also this could run in the visual studio suite right?I just want to be able to do simple document manipulation.I guess if I can do it from VBA it would be easy to figure out what I am doing wrong from C++.

Comment: check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841698%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as a starting point...